# Concatenate an environment variable and a string in C and feed to fopen()

Tags: c, string, environment-variables, concatenation

I have very little knowledge about C and I can't get this simple task to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void load_hex_fw() {
    char *warea = getenv("WORKAREA");
    char hex[] = "/path/to/fw.hex";
    char hexfile; // several trials done here (*hexfile, hexfile[500], etc.)
    strcat(hexfile, *warea);
    strcat(hexfile, hex);
    printf("## %s\n", hexfile);
    FILE *file = fopen(hexfile, "r");
    fclose(file);
}
```

The above code basically opens a file for reading. But since the absolute path of the hex file is very long (and I'm also thinking of reusing this function in the future), I need to feed `fopen()` with a flexible `hexfile` variable. Googling string concatenation always gives me `strcat()`, or `strncat`, but I'm always getting a segmentation fault. I'm getting confused with pointers and references. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must concatenate a string to a string, not a string to a character. The code you posted should not even compile.

Comment: The code should not compile.  You should have `#include <string.h>`.  Since `hexfile` is a single character, not a big array of them, you should get an error for the call to `strcat()`.  You can't pass it to `strcat()` without an `&` in front; but you can't pass it to `strcat()` safely even with the `&` because it needs to be an array.

Comment: Note that `strncat()` is never part of the solution; it is a problem in its own right, and using it makes your problem worse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added some corrections and comments in your code, this should help you:

```
void load_hex_fw() {
    char *warea = getenv("WORKAREA"); //check if getenv returns null
    if(warea == NULL)
    {
    return;
    }
    char hex[] = "/path/to/fw.hex";
    char *hexfile = NULL;//you need char buffer to store string 
    hexfile = malloc(strlen(warea) + stren(hex) + 1);//ENsure hexfile holds full filename
    strcpy(hexfile,warea); //assuming you hold path in warea
    strcat(hexfile, hex);//Assuming ypu hold filename in hex
    printf("## %s\n", hexfile);
    FILE *file = fopen(hexfile, "r");// check if fopen returns NULL
    fclose(file);
    free(hexfile);
}
```

Comment: If the value in `$WORKAREA` is big enough, you get buffer overflow.  You might as well show how to prevent that (and the answer is *not*, repeat ***not***, `strncat()`).

Comment: The `strcpy()` made all the difference. I thought that by just using `strcat()`, `warea` will simply append its string value to `hexfile` (which I keep changing to `*hexfile`, `hexfile[500]`, `*hexfile[]`, etc. just to see which one will finally work) AND store the result to a memory address pointed to by `hexfile`.

Comment: For robust code, MUST check (!=NULL) the returned value from the call to `malloc()` and `fopen()`.   Strongly suggest, when a system function call fails to output a message to `stderr`, that include the text string related to `errno`, Suggest using `perror()` to perform that activity.

Answer (score 0):

`asprintf` allocates memory for you

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    char *warea = getenv("WORKAREA");
    if (!warea) {
        warea = "default"; // or exit
    }
    char hex[] = "/path/to/fw.hex";
    char *hexfile;
    asprintf(&hexfile, "%s%s", warea, hex);
    printf("## %s\n", hexfile);
    // ...
    free(hexfile);
}
```

it accepts `0` but result is hardly what you want for `fopen`

```
## (null)/path/to/fw.hex
```